# How to initialize a constant from a non-constant?

Tags: c++, constants

How can I initialize a constant to use it as a size parameter for a bitset object, such that it takes its value from anothe non-constant variable?

```
int x=2;
int y=Some_Function(x);
const int z=y;
bitset<z> b;
```

Comment: @Tarek: The example you quoted should work fine.

Comment: You can't just declare an int as `const` and use it as the size of an array (without using dynamic allocation). It has to be constant at _compile time_, not runtime.

Comment: If you show us the actual computation, maybe we can help you with some template hackery. Or you could just use `std::vector`...

Comment: If `Some_Function(x);` is simple, add it here and we might be able to make a compile-time equivalent for you.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot do that because size of arrays or the template parameter to`std::bitset` has to be **compile-time constant**, not runtime constant. The `const` value *must* be known at compile-time itself, in order to be used as array-size, or in `std::bitset`.

```
int x = getSize();
const int y = x;  //ok - runtime const. y cannot be changed; x can be changed!
int a[y];         //error in ISO C++ - y is not known at compile time!
std::bitset<y> b; //error in ISO C++ - y is not known at compile time!

const int z = 10; //ok - compile-time const. z cannot be changed!
int c[z];         //ok - z is known at compile time!
std::bitset<z> d; //ok - z is known at compile time!
```

The above code and comments are made according to C++98 and C++03.

However, in C++11, `y` will be compile-time constant, and the code involving `y` would compile **if** `y` is initialized as:

```
 const int y = getSize(); //i.e not using `x` to initialize it.
```

and  `getSize()` is defined as:

```
 constexpr int getSize() { /*return some compile-time constant*/ }
```

The keyword `constexpr` has been added to C++11 to define [generalize constant expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Generalized_constant_expressions).

Comment: In C++11 const int y = getSize(); could work, when getSize() is constexpr

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between a constant variable and a compile-time constant. Compare:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const int i = argc; // constant
}
```

This variable `i` is constant with the function scope, but its value is unknown at compile time.

On the other hand, the following two are *compile-time* constants:

```
const int a = 12;

int f(int n) { return 2 * n; }  // see below

const int b = f(6);
```

Both `a` and `b` are known at compile time.

Only compile-time constants can be used as array sizes or template parameters! (Templates are essentially code generation machines, so the code has to be generated before the final program can be compiled.)

```
std::bitset<a> B1; // OK, same as std::bitset<12>
std::bitset<b> B2; // OK in C++11, not allowed in C++98/03

// but, in main() above:
std::bitset<i> B3; // Cannot do, we don't know i at compile-time!
```

Note that in C++98/03, `b` is not actually formally recognized as a compile-time constant. C++11 fixes this by allowing `f` to be declared `constexpr`, meaning it's allowed to compute compile-time constant expressions (if all its arguments are themselves constant).

Comment: The answer appropriately answers the intent of the OP, probably you should also mention that that the code snippet S/He mentions is perfectly valid and that is the least of his problems.

Comment: @Als: I think the OP has edited the question, now the snippet is no longer valid :-)

Comment: Woops, My Slow Beasty Dell! :-)

Comment: @Kerrek: `std::bitset<b> B2` wouldn't compile, in my opinion. The compiler wouldn't execute `f(6)`  to initialize `b` at compile-time itself.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I have a question about Example 2. You can achieve something similar in C++11 with `constexpr`, but out of curiosity, is `b` really known at compile time? I.e., does the compiler actually evaluate `f(6)`?

Comment: Jacob, Nawaz: If you declare `constexpr int f(int n) { return 2*n; }`, then if you pass a compile-time constant into `f`, you get a compile-time constant out. It's like writing `const int b = 2 * 6;`. You can still use `f` in other contexts, like `f(argc)`, but `constexpr` allows the constness to propagate.

Comment: @Kerrek: You should write this in the comment itself. Its not exactly "ditto". Make the difference very clear from the beginning itself, as to where you're talking about C++11 also!

Comment: @Nawaz: Sure, can do... mind you, I'm saying that `b` is always a compile-time constant, only that in C++98/03 the language doesn't capture that and so you cannot use it that way -- but it's always been known at compile-time!

Answer (score 0):

Let's distinguish between compile-time constants and variables with `const` slapped on them. Yours is the latter kind; only the former kind can serve as array size (before C++0).